# SQL query defining Column type as float with 3 decimal numbers

Tags: sql

This is a simple example of what is not working for me:

```
CREATE TABLE Vertex(
PointID CHARACTER(15) PRIMARY KEY,
Height FLOAT(6,3)
);
```

After input like this:

```
INSERT INTO Vertex values("Tryout 1",555.22689562);
```

I expect the Height to be saved with the value: 555.227
However it is not the case for me, I keep finding the whole number being saved.

Could you point me to an alternate of how to define a column type and contain the format xxxxxx.xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change float to decimal and it will work.

`Height decimal(6,3)`

Float is an approximate number data type. Using float may cause loss of precision, and using float data type for equality may not work all times.

Decimal data type is fixed precision data type. For using decimal data types, you will need to convert to the data type like `convert(decimal(6,3), <number>)`.

In case of insert query, it is done implicitly though.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. It is actually weird why it doesn't appear in MSDN field type table!